# dont include the last line in matching between patterns in awk and sed, but include the first

Tags: bash, awk, sed, asa

Apologies - Iv'e now edited the title - the title was originally the opposite of what I wanted.

I want to include the first line of the pattern, and every line up to the occurence of the end pattern. The end pattern, is a subset of the start pattern, so sed is behaving differently to AWK.

The purpose of this is to build a bash function that enumerates Cisco ASA object-groups of type network.

Further to this, if any of the lines in the lines of output contain "group-object" - then that group object also needs to be enumerated.  I am sure with with some loops, if's and awk's and or sed's this can be done.

e.g.

```
object-group network OBJECT-GROUP-DADDY
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0
 group-object NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.3.1.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network ANY-OTHER-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.11.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.22.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

Would return:

```
object-group network OBJECT-GROUP-DADDY
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0
 group-object NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP --+ EXPANDED BELOW
 ----network-object 10.11.1.0 255.255.255.0
 ----network-object 10.22.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

At the moment - I cant even get the first part working (without enumerating nested groups)
Also - nested groups, could have nested groups ! argh

```
sed -n '/object-group network OBJECT-GROUP-DADDY/,/object-group network/p' ASA_CONFIG.cfg
```

gives me what i need, but does include the first line of the END pattern, which Is the start of an object group I dont care about.

The awk version doesn't seem to return anything, i'm guessing because the end pattern is a sub-string of the start pattern:

```
awk '/object-group network OBJECT-GROUP-DADDY/,/object-group network/p' ASA_CONFIG.cfg
```

there was a guide about this using next and flags, but I could not make head or tail of it from a bunch of different sites.

OK here is added information:

In answer to your questions, no I do not know the awk language, nor sed. I'm a network engineer - and I guess for those of you that do not dabble in that discipline, why I want to achieve this is a mystery to you.  I am terrible at programming, and my linux is very weak.

The access control lists in a cisco ASA configuration are generally built with access lists like this:

access-list ACCESS-LIST extended permit ip object-group SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP object-group DESTINATION-OBJECT-GROUP

Anything in capitals has been entered by a human, some point in time, lower case words being reserved by cisco, for parsing etc.  The "object groups" are like arrays in a programming language. These access lists may also contain more than one line, or have networks explicitly defined, rather than use object groups.

I would like to enumerate all of the object groups entries, for both the source and destination object group that is in a specified Access-list.  The format of these object-groups is as below

```
object-group network DESTINATION-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.33.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.44.1.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network ANY-OTHER-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0
 group-object NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.3.1.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.11.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.22.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

In the above example, using the Access control list presented earlier, I would like the source object group output:

```
object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0
group-object NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.3.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

however notice that this object group named SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP also contains a group-object, which is a reserved word that means - this is a nested object group, and needs to be read in from somewhere else in the config.

So the output would need to be :

```
object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0
 group-object NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP
 ---enumerated----network-object 10.3.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.3.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

We would not want any output from the other object-groups that are not a part of the access list, or not nested in the top level access list.  This concept is similar to nested groups in Active Directory.

Ill now attempt to give you some pseudo code:

AWK print the object-group names/variables from the access-list using the awk print $6 and awk print $9

access-list ACCESS-LIST extended permit ip object-group SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP object-group DESTINATION-OBJECT-GROUP

store each of these as some variable, then enumerate.
like $source-object-group-name, $destination-object-group-name

function enumerate-object-group input $source-object-group-name

So if $source-object-group-name = "SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP" do some kind of explicit pattern matching that wont match "SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP1", (some kind of grep -w style thing) print each line below. this is becuase many object groups, are just longer named ones that others.  E.g like run is a substring of running

(1) print the "title line" 
object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP

(2)Check if line starts with "group-object"(notice this is a reversed reserved name, so cisco can differentiate)
---> YES? send the value of this "object-group" to another function, just like this one.  This value can be grabbed with awk print $2

---> NO ? print the line, because its just a "normal" one as it doesn't start with "group-object"

```
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

---> YES? send the value of this "object-group" to another function, just like this one.  This value can be grabbed with awk print $2 (goto 1?)

(3) continue down the configuration until we hit some text that starts with "object-group network" BUT then doesn't contain the explicit name of the original group object, meaning - it is a new object-group that we don't care about, as it is not the one we are pulling from the access list nor its not one that was nested, that we are expanding.

pump the $destination-object-group-name into the function
repeat for all lines in teh access-list

I understand this is complicated, and that there is two levels (or more) of nested groups going on here.  let me know if you need more info.

I couldn't get the comments to display properly, was trying the double space for line breaks.

I tried your suggestion, replacing the end sed p with {$d;p} however, I go the same output:

```
[nickc@localhost ~]$ sed -n '/object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP/,/object-group network/{$d;p}' ASA_CONFIG.cfg
object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0
 group-object NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.3.1.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP
[nickc@localhost ~]$ sed -n '/object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP/,/object-group network/p' ASA_CONFIG.cfg
object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0
 group-object NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.3.1.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP
```

We need to make sure the last line is omitted.
Im testing with the below text:

```
nickc@localhost ~]$ cat ASA_CONFIG.cfg
object-group network DESTINATION-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.33.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.44.1.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network ANY-OTHER-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0
 group-object NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.3.1.0 255.255.255.0
object-group network NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP
 network-object 10.11.1.0 255.255.255.0
 network-object 10.22.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

Comment: I hardly can understand what you are trying to explain.

Comment: What does it mean the "p" at the end of the second pattern in the awk code?

Comment: @Jdamian it means the author does not know the awk language.

Comment: @NickC so far you've shown us a bunch of lines of text and told us that is the input. Then you've shown us a bunch of other lines of text and told us that is the expected output. You now need to tell us why. And I don't mean "because this is tool foo or standard blah output and I need it in metacode X...". I mean tell us how each string in your input is mapped to each string in your output and where the additional text in the output is coming from and why some of the text from the input does not appear in the output. i.e. just tell us how you want to map the text from input to output.

Comment: OK sorry what im trying to do, is enumerate Object groups, that may contain other object groups. So in the text below:

Comment: [nickc@localhost ~]$ sed -n '/object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP/,/object-group network/{$d;p}' ASA_CONFIG.cfg  
object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP  
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0  
 network-object 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0  
 group-object NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP  
 network-object 10.3.1.0 255.255.255.0  
object-group network NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP

Answer (score 1):

`sed -n '/object-group network OBJECT-GROUP-DADDY/,/object-group network/{$d;p}' ASA_CONFIG.cfg`

The $d will delete the last line of the pattern.

Update: the solution above should work as far as I know yet doesn't for some reason (perhaps a sed bug) - the following is a workaround:

`sed -n '/object-group network OBJECT-GROUP-DADDY/,/object-group network/p' ASA_CONFIG.cfg | sed '$d'`

Comment: @A.DanischewskiI get the same from both, and both contain the end pattern:  `[nickc@localhost ~]$ sed -n '/object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP/,/object-group network/{$d;p}' ASA_CONFIG.cfg  
object-group network SOURCE-OBJECT-GROUP  
 network-object 10.1.1.0 255.255.255.0  
 network-object 10.2.1.0 255.255.255.0  
 group-object NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP  
 network-object 10.3.1.0 255.255.255.0  
object-group network NESTED-OBJECT-GROUP`

Comment: It looks like a sed bug, I think it should work - if you put for your data {6d;p} it gets rid of the last line. I updated my answer to rid the last line.

Comment: your workaround works, I couldnt get the 6d to work. that will be fine, thank you very much. now I think ill pose a different thread question on linux questions, as the rest is more about bash scripting that the intricacies of sed/awk  THANKS!

Comment: @NickC When you are ready, you can select Choose this Answer to select an answer and it will close the question.

Comment: Just what I needed! Thanks so much. I needed a similar approach, because `sed` always prints out the pattern space and there is no direct way I know of which would exclude both the starting and ending pattern space from printout. It was the tricky `{1d;$d;p}` syntax with curly braces that I didn't know about.